# categorised dropdown select2

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

i am using select2 multi select dropdown, and it works perfectly but my problem is, i want to categorise the drop down list of the same. Here is my code

```
<script src="/static/select2.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="test" value=""/>
```

and js

```
$(test).select2({
data:data,
multiple: true,
width: "100%",
placeholder:"None Selected",
closeOnSelect:false,
});
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear could use a re-writing or more elaboration.

Comment: her is my [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mQhsf/) i want to categorise hai,hellow as one group and yes,no as another

Comment: @shaunhusain here is my updated [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mQhsf/2/)

Comment: I answered, but was truly disappointed in the lack of AngularJS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(test).select2({
  data: 
    [
      {
        text: 'GREETINGS',
        children: 
        [
          { 'id': 1, text: 'hai' }, 
          { 'id': 2, text: 'hellow'}, 
        ]
      }, 
      {
        text: 'QUESTIONS',
        children: 
        [
          { 'id': 3, 'text': 'yes' }, 
          { 'id': 4, 'text': 'no'  }
        ]
      }
    ],
  multiple: true,
  width: "100%",
  placeholder: "None Selected",
  closeOnSelect: false,
});
```